# Vue JS materal design with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-material

I'm trying to use Vue JS material design with TypeScript, but it's not supported out of the box. Following [this](https://github.com/vuematerial/vue-material/issues/662) GitHub issue I've been trying to add declare a custom module, but without success.
My app is created with `vue create my-app` command

I created a new file in src: `types/vue-material/index.d.ts`:

```
declare module 'vue-material' {
    import _Vue from "vue";
    
    export function MdButton(Vue: typeof _Vue, options?: any): void
    export function MdContent(Vue: typeof _Vue, options?: any): void
    export function MdTabs(Vue: typeof _Vue, options?: any): void
}
```

I added type roots and excluded the folder from `tsconfig`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...
    "typeRoots": [
      "src/types",
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  // ...
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "src/types"
  ]
}
```

But still I'm getting an error when trying to import `VueMaterial`:

```
import { MdButton } from 'vue-material';
```

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'vue-material'. 'C:/.../my-app/node_modules/vue-material/dist/vue-material.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/vue-material` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'vue-material';`
```

What I'm doing wrong?